# Why can't I read frames from FLIR Lepton to STM32?

Tags: stm32, spi, flir

I'm trying to integrate between FLIR Lepton 2 (through Lepton Breakout board v1.4) and STM32F4 Discovery board. The program is simple: Reading a 80x60 frame from the Lepton (via SPI) and sending the frame through UART to the client (in my case, a Flutter application). All of the components work very well except for the frame reading from the Lepton.

I continue to get the same buffer that I think it's an error message. Needless to say that it's not a valid image frame. I red the datasheet and I didn't find any clue that will help me.

Here is my 2 functions to reading and handling the frame image data:

```
    void ReadFrame(uint8_t *frameData)
    {
        uint8_t *tmp = frameData;

        GPIO_PinState csState;
        uint8_t write_data = 0x0;

        csState = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(CS_PORT, CS_PIN);
        if (csState == GPIO_PIN_SET)
        {
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CS_PORT, CS_PIN, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
            HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, &write_data, sizeof(write_data), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

            for (uint16_t i = 0; i < VOSPI_VIDEO_PACKETS_PER_FRAME; i++)
            {
                HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, tmp, VOSPI_PACKET_LENGTH, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
                tmp += VOSPI_PACKET_LENGTH;
            }

            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CS_PORT, CS_PIN, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        }
    }
```

This function receives the current frame and puts the frame's data into a `uint8_t*` buffer. Firstly it sets the `CS` pin-state to `LOW`, then it handles an SPI request, iterating through each packet (a row in the frame) by reading that packet, and finally it sets the `CS` to `HIGH`.

```
    void handleFrame(uint8_t *frameData, uint8_t *newFrameData)
    {
        int packetCount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < VOSPI_PACKET_LENGTH * packetCount; i +=
            VOSPI_PACKET_LENGTH)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < VOSPI_PACKET_LENGTH - VOSPI_HEADER_SIZE; j++)
            {
                newFrameData[(i / VOSPI_PACKET_LENGTH)
                    * (VOSPI_PACKET_LENGTH - VOSPI_HEADER_SIZE) + j] =
                    frameData[i + VOSPI_HEADER_SIZE + j];
            }
        }
    }
```

In the datasheet, it mentioned that each packet consists of an `header` (4 bytes) and a `payload` (the actual data, 160 bytes, in `Raw14` each pixel is 2 bytes sized). This function iterates through each packet in the frame by removing its header.

In the main code, I call those function like that:

```
    uint8_t frameData[VOSPI_PACKET_LENGTH * VOSPI_VIDEO_PACKETS_PER_FRAME];
    uint8_t newFrameData[COLS * ROWS * PIXEL_SIZE];

    memset(frameData, 0, sizeof(frameData));
    memset(newFrameData, 0, sizeof(newFrameData));

    while(/* Condition for connection */)
    {
        ReadFrame(frameData);
        handleFrame(frameData, newFrameData);

        // Sending 'newFrameData` via UART
    }
```

Those 2 functions result with the same buffer: `[83, 101, 114, 105, 97, 108, 32, 80, 111, 114, 116, 32, 84, 101, 115, ...] (9600 bytes)`.

Here are my SPI settings:

```
    static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
    {
        /* SPI1 parameter configuration*/
        hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
        hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
        hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
        hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_16BIT;
        hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_HIGH;
        hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_2EDGE;
        hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
        hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;
        hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
        hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
        hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_ENABLE;
        hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;

        if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
        {
            Error_Handler();
        }
    }
```

I connected all SPI pins (`CS`, `CLK`, `MISO` and `MOSI`), `VIN` and `GND` in the Lepton to their related pins in the STM32.

Comment: Please help. I'm stuck on this integration problem for more than 2 months.

Comment: First, the call to HAL_SPI_Transmit() in ReadFrame seems unnecessary.  Why are you transmitting?  You should only receive.  Second, I don't see where you are checking the packet header for discard packets.